# Is loot redeemed from Loot-o-Grams scaled to your level?

Tags: borderlands-3

The Dinklebot, a random spawn at Skywell-27, drops Loot-o-Grams that can be traded in to Crazy Earl for the occasional Legendary. Assuming you had no Mayhem Mode/ TVHM activated (for example, you are on your first playthrough), does the loot you receive from Earl scale to your level even though the Dinklebot does not?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the loot you get from Earl when redeeming the tokens is scaled to your level, even though you got the token from a level 25 Dinkelbot.

What I didn't test is if the tokes are scaled to the level which you had when you killed the Dinkelbot.